# ASP.NET MVC Identity Backward Cookie Expire Time

Tags: asp.net, model-view-controller, cookies

[image: chrome cookies page]

there is something wrong. i use 30 minutes expire and validate time but its doing negative 23 days. i check my computer datetime but cant figure out

my StartupAuth.cs is here

```
public partial class Startup
{

    // For more information on configuring authentication, please visit https://go.microsoft.com/fwlink/?LinkId=301864
    public void ConfigureAuth(IAppBuilder app)
    {
        app.CreatePerOwinContext(ApplicationDbContext.Create);
        app.CreatePerOwinContext<ApplicationUserManager>(ApplicationUserManager.Create);
        app.CreatePerOwinContext<ApplicationSignInManager>(ApplicationSignInManager.Create);

        app.UseCookieAuthentication(new CookieAuthenticationOptions
        {
            AuthenticationType = DefaultAuthenticationTypes.ApplicationCookie,
            LoginPath = new PathString("/Account/Login"),
            Provider = new CookieAuthenticationProvider
            {
                OnValidateIdentity = SecurityStampValidator.OnValidateIdentity<ApplicationUserManager, ApplicationUser>(
                    validateInterval: TimeSpan.FromMinutes(30),
                    regenerateIdentity: (manager, user) => user.GenerateUserIdentityAsync(manager))
            },
            SlidingExpiration = true,
            ExpireTimeSpan = TimeSpan.FromMinutes(30)
        });

    }
}
```

Answer (score -1, accepted):

Interesting thing but i use
`ExpireTimeSpan = TimeSpan.FromDays(24)` 
for after 12 hour. i cant find why